# How to handle Query builder with date formats

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I would like to show only the events for which startdate begins as of tomorrow. How can I proceed ? For the moment it's taking h:i:s into account as well.

```
public function display()
{
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->loadModel('Events');
    $events = $this->Events
        ->find()
        ->contain(['Categories', 'Venues'])
        ->limit(5)
        ->order(['events.startdate' => 'ASC'])
        ->where(['events.startdate >' => $now]);
    $this->set('upcomingEvents', $events);
}
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
public function display()
{
    $now = date('Y-m-d');

    $this->loadModel('Events');
    $events = $this->Events
        ->find()
        ->contain(['Categories', 'Venues'])
        ->limit(5)
        ->order(['events.startdate' => 'ASC'])
        ->where(['date_format("%Y-%m-%d", events.startdate)' => $now]);
    $this->set('upcomingEvents', $events);
}
```

Comment: Try: `'Events.startdate' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to format the date in the query and lose the indexing functionality, instead compare against a datetime string that uses `00:00:00` for the time part, eg the start of the day.

You can achieve this easily with `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')`, however that would be today, not tomorrow, you'd need to feed `date()` with a timestamp like `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('+1 day'))`.

You can also use the datetime functionality that ships with CakePHP. Today `\Cake\Chronos\Date::tomorrow()` would create a date object representing `2021-10-06` where the time part will always be `00:00:00`.

```php
->where(['Events.startdate >=' => \Cake\Chronos\Date::tomorrow()])
```

The ORM will automatically format the date object accordingly to the column type, so for your I suppose `DATETIME` column, it would end up as `2021-10-06 00:00:00` in the SQL.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Date & Time](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/time.html)**
- **[Chronos Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/chronos/2/en/index.html)**

Comment: Always better, IMO, to avoid the `date` function, and instead use Cake's provided classes, as those classes include a way to set the date to be used. That's tremendously useful when unit testing.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Oh, completely forgot about that. Yeah, being able to set a fixed time when testing is another big plus!

Comment: It looks like most (maybe even all supported DBMS) don't even need the time part when doing less/greater comparisons, seems in those cases they assume `00:00:00` by default if it's omitted. How did I never notice that in the last 20 years???

Comment: Thank you both ! I didn't even find Cake's provided classes in the queries documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way to proceed, but it using function DATA_FORMAT()

```
DATE_FORMAT(events.startdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

So here is the query :

```
public function display()
{
    $now = date('Y-m-d');

    $this->loadModel('Events');
    $events = $this->Events
        ->find()
        ->contain(['Categories', 'Venues'])
        ->limit(5)
        ->order(['events.startdate' => 'ASC'])
        ->where(['DATE_FORMAT(events.startdate, "%Y-%m-%d") >' => $now]);
        
    $this->set('upcomingEvents', $events);
}
```

Or we can use it in a conditions array as well

```
public function display()
{
    $this->loadModel('Events');
    $events = $this->Events
    ->find('all', array('conditions' => array('DATE_FORMAT(events.startdate, "%Y-%m-%d") >' => date('Y-m-d'))))
    ->contain(['Categories', 'Venues'])
    ->limit(5)
    ->order(['events.startdate' => 'ASC']);

    $this->set('upcomingEvents', $events);
}
```

Comment: explain a bit more what you've done to solve the question. If you do so it increases the quality of the answer and people are more likely to up-vote if you do. End of Review.